# Stopforeground behavior and notifications

Tags: android, android-service

I've got an `intentService` and in `onHandleIntent()` I call `startForeground()` at beginning and `stopForeground` at the end of the method. When I call `stopForeground(false)` the notification is removed even if I specified to kept it around. Documentation says:

“if you stop the service while it’s still running in the foreground, then the notification is also removed.”

So it seems that when the `intentService` calls `stopSelf()` for some reason the service is again in foreground state. The only way the right behaviour is to create a new notification after `stopForeground(true)`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score -2):

An `IntentService` stops itself when the work is done in `onHandleIntent`. If the `IntentService` has stopped, why would you want to continue showing a notification? It sounds like you should be using a regular `Service`, where you control the call to `stopSelf`.

It makes perfect sense that the notification *would* automatically be removed by a call to `stopSelf`, whether or not you call `stopForeground`. The service is done.

Comment: Because the notification contains the result and it's a good thing if it's not removed. I call stopforeground before the end of onHandleIntent as I said. In addition your comments makes no sense because if I post a notification after stopforeground (and then before stopSelf()) it works.